# Undefined variable: stockcategory in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I was trying to create a drop category option from database so admin can be able to select product category from the select option. But after I select from the database in my DashboardController and tried to include it in my select option in the form an error appeared in the form page.

Here is the error that was been displayed:

ErrorException in 73cd6543c61fa0a342e4d528a9bc24bd5c4c4cbe.php line 29:
Undefined variable: stockcategory (View: C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views\dashboard\stock-create.blade.php)

Here is stock-create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')
@section('title', 'Stock Create')
@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="portlet light bordered">

                <div class="portlet-body form">
                    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'post','class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}
                    <div class="form-body">


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Name : </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input name="name" value="" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" required placeholder="Product Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Category : </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <select name="product_id" id="" class="form-control input-lg" required>
                                    <option value="">Select One</option>

                                    @foreach($stockcategory as $c)
                                        <option value="{{ $c->id }}">{{ $c->category }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Quantity : </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product-quantity" placeholder="Product Quantity">                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Buying Price : </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="buying-price" placeholder="Buying Price"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Selling Price : </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="saleing-price" placeholder="Selling Price">
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn blue btn-block margin-top-10"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Add</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!---ROW-->


@endsection
```

DashboardController.php

```
//Stocks Category
    public function createStockCategory()
    {
        $data['site_title'] = $this->site_title;
        $data['page_title'] = "Create Stock Category";

        return view('dashboard.stockcategory-create',$data);
    }
    public function storeStockCategory(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
           'category' => 'required|unique:stock_category,category',

        ]);
        try {
            $stockcategory = Input::except('_method','_token');
            StockCategory::create($stockcategory);
            session()->flash('message', 'Stock Category Created Successfully. ');
            Session::flash('type', 'success');
            return redirect()->back();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            session()->flash('message', 'Some Problem Occurs, Please Try Again!');
            Session::flash('type', 'danger');
            return redirect()->back();
        }


    }
    public function showStockCategory()
    {
        $data['site_title'] = $this->site_title;
        $data['page_title'] = "All Stock Category";
        $data['stockcategory'] = StockCategory::orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(100);
        return view('dashboard.stockcategory-show',$data);
    }
    public function editStockCategory($id)
    {
        $data['stockcategory'] = StockCategory::findOrFail($id);
        $data['site_title'] = $this->site_title;
        $data['page_title'] = 'Edit Stock Category';
        //$data['stock'] = Stock::all();
        $date = StockCategory::find($id);
        return view('dashboard.stockcategory-edit',$data);

    }
    public function updateStockCategory(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $stockscategory = StockCategory::findOrFail($id);
        $this->validate($request,[
           'category' => 'required|unique:stock_category,category,'.$stockscategory->id,

        ]);
        try {
            $stockcategory = Input::except('_method','_token');
            $stockscategory->fill($stockcategory)->save();
            session()->flash('message', 'Stock category Updated Successfully.');
            Session::flash('type', 'success');
            return redirect()->back();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            session()->flash('message', 'Some Problem Occurs, Please Try Again!');
            Session::flash('type', 'danger');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
    public function deleteStockCategory(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            if ($request->input('id') === '') {
                session()->flash('message', 'Oops, bad request!');
                Session::flash('type', 'danger');
                return redirect()->back();
            }else{
                $stockcategory = StockCategory::findOrFail($request->input('id'));
                $stockcategory->delete();
                session()->flash('message', 'Stock Category Deleted Successfully.');
                Session::flash('type', 'success');
                return redirect()->back();
            }

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            session()->flash('message', 'Some Problem Occurs, Please Try Again!');
            Session::flash('type', 'danger');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

Routes.php

```
/* Stock Category Route List */
Route::get('stockcategory-create',['as'=>'stockcategory-create','uses'=>'DashboardController@createStockCategory']);
Route::post('stockcategory-create',['as'=>'stockcategory-store','uses'=>'DashboardController@storeStockCategory']);
Route::get('stockcategory-show',['as'=>'stockcategory-show','uses'=>'DashboardController@showStockCategory']);
Route::get('stockcategory-edit/{id}',['as'=>'stockcategory-edit','uses'=>'DashboardController@editStockCategory']);
Route::put('stockcategory-edit/{id}',['as'=>'stockcategory-update','uses'=>'DashboardController@updateStockCategory']);
Route::delete('stockcategory-delete',['as'=>'stockcategory-delete','uses'=>'DashboardController@deleteStockCategory']);
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `$stockcategory` in your view but you need to send it first from your controller in the method of `createStockCategory()`! Like: `return view('dashboard.stockcategory-create', ['stockcategory' => $data]);`

Comment: @HirenGohel, could you point me in the right direction? Please.

Comment: Try: `return view('dashboard.stockcategory-create', ['stockcategory' => $data]);` Refer this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$stockcategory` in your view but you need to send it first from your controller in the method of `createStockCategory()`! Try Like this:

```
public function createStockCategory()
{
    $data['site_title'] = $this->site_title;
    $data['page_title'] = "Create Stock Category";

    return view('dashboard.stockcategory-create', ['stockcategory' => $data]);
}
```

Refer this [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views)!

Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here in your this function pass `$data` as `stockcategory`

```
public function createStockCategory()
{
    $data['site_title'] = $this->site_title;
    $data['page_title'] = "Create Stock Category";

    return view('dashboard.stockcategory-create',['stockcategory' => $data]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for your precious time, Well appreciated.